# Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream for Hystrix Dashboard with Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, runtimeexception, hystrix

I have microservices project with Spring Cloud, the snippet from parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

All services are running under Eureka server:

[image]

All services are running fine. I can call make appropriate calls with Postman and everything works fine.

I have separate service which handles Hystrix dashboard, a snippet from `pom`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Configuration main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class DashboardApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DashboardApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

and config `yaml` file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Dashboard

server:
  port: 8000

eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
    registerWithEureka: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

I have next dashboard looking:

[image]

Full stack trace from the console is [here](https://pastebin.com/GL1gHQH6). Following is some snippet:

```
2018-04-12 11:28:25.089 ERROR 15762 --- [qtp295055909-16] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Error proxying request: http://localhost:8082/hystrix.stream
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.HystrixDashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet.doGet(HystrixDashboardConfiguration.java:208)
....
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
...
```

Service itself is accessible with spring actuator:

[image]

snippet from it's `pom`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Config class looks:

```
@EnableHystrix
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class TableApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TableApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**How to solve this issue?**

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

Problem was that Controller API has to be market by [HystrixCommand](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html) annotation.

Snippet from a documentation:

```
Turbine AMQP by Spring Cloud offers a different model where each
application instance pushes the metrics from Hystrix commands to
Turbine through a central AMQP broker.
```

I added it without any parameters to all Controller's methods, like following:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GuestController {
    private DinnerService dinnerService;

    @HystrixCommand
    @PostMapping("/dinner")
    public Integer startDinner(@RequestBody List<Integer> menuItems) {
        return dinnerService.startDinner(menuItems);
    }

    @HystrixCommand
    @DeleteMapping("/dinner/{tableId}")
    public void finishDinner(@PathVariable Integer tableId) {
        dinnerService.finishDinner(tableId);
    }
}
```

And now all works like charming:

[image]

Now I understand that I was so close to it.

Comment: Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444872/org-springframework-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard-hystrixdashboardconfiguratio ?

Answer (score 18):

For those who are using spring boot 2, the `hystrix.stream` endpoint has been moved to `/actuator/hystrix.stream`.

For me this url worked:

```
http://localhost:8082/actuator/hystrix.stream
```

And yes, have this actuator endpoint enabled via following property:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream
```

Of course you must have the actutator dependency included in your project.

Comment: Could you pls guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444872/org-springframework-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard-hystrixdashboardconfiguratio ?

Comment: also add this in application.properties: `hystrix.dashboard.proxyStreamAllowList=*`

Answer (score 5):

Hystrix dashboard itself can't be used for monitoring several instances at once. The thing that you need is [turbine](https://github.com/Netflix/turbine/wiki)+dashboard. In a couple of words turbine is an aggregator for several hystrix metrics streams.

Configuration of instance:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: hystrix.stream, info, health

spring:
  application:
    name: WRITING
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

The important thing here is to expose hystix.stream actuator. This endpoint will be used by the turbine to read metrics. Also, do not forget to add actuators starter.

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

If you did everything correctly `http://localhost:8080/actuator/hystrix.stream` endpoint should become available.

Turbine config will look like:

```
server:
      port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: TURBINE

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

turbine:
  appConfig: WRITING,READING
  clusterNameExpression: new String('default')
```

In `appConfig`, you should specify service names for monitoring.

After starting turbine `localhost:8888/turbine.stream` will be available.

You can pass this URL to the dashboard and monitor all data aggregated for hystrix commands of discovered instances.

[Github](https://github.com/Ivan-Lymar/spring-cloud) project example.

p.s.
Dependencies that you have used are deprecated. Please check [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix)

Comment: I added `management` section to service's config file. Actuator dependency has already added. However, `http://localhost:8082/actuator/hystrix.stream` shows `Whitelabel Error Page`. Also, `http://localhost:8082/health` and `http://localhost:8082/hystrix.stream` show info the same as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @nazar_art seems that I've noticed the difference. Your are using spring-cloud-starter-hystrix, when I used spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix. Same for hystrix-dashboard. Is it possible  for you to switch?

Comment: I tried to change it, and my service failed with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/hystrix/contrib/javanica/aop/aspectj/HystrixCommandAspect`

Comment: @nazar_art updated my answer with github repo link with working example.

Comment: To make long story short, it failed with few reasons: [ReadingApplication](https://pastebin.com/3aj0HfgT), [Dashboard](https://pastebin.com/KUTBvqBh)

Comment: @nazar_art removed error from ReadingApp. Updated readme with detailed instruction. Please take a look

Comment: I updated sources. Tried to follow readme. Client service had some exceptions. However, it worked and printed `book` on a browser and actuator was working fine. Dashboard startup failed during the start with [stack trace](https://pastebin.com/xWBdVLgK). Turbine started also fine.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this issue for the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.0.7.RELEASE` and `spring-cloud-dependencies` version `Finchley.SR2` by adding below two properties in the **`application.properties`**.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added this in your application.properties.

```
hystrix.dashboard.proxy-stream-allow-list=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with the latest version of Spring-boot(2.3.3-XXX) and spring-cloud (Hoxton.SR7) but when I did the downgrade the version in pom.xml file then it starts working fine for me.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Hope, this would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct your hystrix.stream url to `http://localhost:8082/actuator/hystrix.stream`
2. Exposure 'hystrix.steam' web endpoints in your hystrix application's config file:

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'hystrix.stream'
```

3. Make sure you have added your host to `hystrix.dashboard.proxyStreamAllowList`, in your config file of hystrix-dashboard application, it looks like:

```yaml
hystrix:
  dashboard:
    proxy-stream-allow-list:
      - 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 0):

check details on
github: https://github.com/HuiyingWang0108/hystrix-dashboard
related microservice:
https://github.com/HuiyingWang0108/cloud-gateway
https://github.com/HuiyingWang0108/registry-service
In my case:
app like this:
[image]
Step1:
(1) change pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

(2) added below in the application.yml

```
hystrix:
  dashboard:
    proxy-stream-allow-list: "*"
```

(3) and then start app, open:

```
http://localhost:9295/hystrix
```

works:

Step2:
(1) added below in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

(2)added below in the application.yml

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: hystrix.stream, info, health
```

(3) Open:
http://localhost:9191/actuator/hystrix.steam
shows:
[image]