# Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream in hystrix dashboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I am trying to build simple spring cloud application using  Netflix eureka service discovery and hystrix circuit breaker .

**Circuit Breaker Service:**

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class PluralsightEurekaFastpassConsoleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PluralsightEurekaFastpassConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix
            </artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Hystrix Dashboard**

```
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class PluralsiteHystrixDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PluralsiteHystrixDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**hystrix dashboard** 
[image: hystrix-dashboard]

**Console Log**

> 2018-07-04 20:15:25.051  INFO 17516 --- [nio-8088-exec-1]
>   ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet :  Proxy opening connection
>   to: http://localhost:8088/actuator/hystrix.stream 2018-07-04
>   20:15:25.052  INFO 17516 --- [nio-8088-exec-6]
>   ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet :  Proxy opening connection
>   to: http://localhost:8088/actuator/hystrix.stream 2018-07-04
>   20:15:25.058  WARN 17516 --- [nio-8088-exec-1]
>   ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection
>   to http://localhost:8088/actuator/hystrix.stream : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404 
>   2018-07-04 20:15:25.058  WARN 17516 --- [nio-8088-exec-6]
>   ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection
>   to http://localhost:8088/actuator/hystrix.stream : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404

I tried  [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream for Hystrix Dashboard with Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792290/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-for-hystrix-dashboard-with-spring-clo)

but the problem still exist .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't provide enough information, so probably the best would be to make sure that:

1. A **Circuit Breaker Service** is running on port 8088
2. A spring boot actuator endpoints in the Circuit breaker service are indeed deployed and accessible under `actuator` context path. In order to check where the actuator actually is, analyze the startup logs, and if there is no information about deployed endpoints, add `--debug` to the application startup of the micro-service.

It looks like the second step will reveal the real issue.
Then the actuator context path can be set up by using `management.context-path` or hystix dashboard should be customized

Comment: Thanks Mark ,yes  the problem in the actuator context path . solved by setting   [management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream]  in the application.properties and accessing the hystrix stream via [http://localhost:8081/actuator/hystrix.stream]