# Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream in Spring Cloud + Hystrix + Turbine - MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine

I already went through the link: [Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream for Hystrix Dashboard with Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792290/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-for-hystrix-dashboard-with-spring-clo) and tried few options, but nothing worked out for yet.
I am developing **Spring Cloud Code + Hystrix + Turbine**.

Could you please let me know what is the issue ? I am using Spring Boot `v2.0.4.RELEASE`.

[image]

[image]

**HystrixDashboardApplication.java**

```
@EnableTurbine
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@SpringBootApplication
public class HystrixDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

`tollrate-billboard` application has the following code
**TollrateBillboardApplication.java**

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class TollrateBillboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TollrateBillboardApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DashboardController.java**

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getTollRateBackup")
    @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
    public String GetTollRate(@RequestParam int stationId, Model m) {

        TollRate tr = restTemplate.getForObject("http://pluralsight-toll-service/tollrate/" + stationId, TollRate.class);
        System.out.println("stationId: " + stationId);
        m.addAttribute("rate", tr.getCurrentRate());
        return "dashboard";
    }

    public String getTollRateBackup(@RequestParam int stationId, Model m) { 
        System.out.println("Fallback operation called");
        m.addAttribute("rate", "1.00");
        return "dashboard";
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.properties**

```
spring.application.name=pluralsight-tollrate-billboard
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8082
# eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

#http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_environment_changes
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream
```

**CURL Command Result:**

```
curl "http://localhost:8085/clusters"
```

**output**

```
[
    {
        "name": "PLURALSIGHT-FASTPASS-CONSOLE",
        "link": "http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=PLURALSIGHT-FASTPASS-CONSOLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "PLURALSIGHT-TOLLRATE-BILLBOARD",
        "link": "http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=PLURALSIGHT-TOLLRATE-BILLBOARD"
    }
]
```

**EDIT-1::**, I am using "hystrix-turbine"

```
@EnableTurbineStream
@SpringBootApplication
public class HystrixTurbineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixTurbineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm getting below error:

```
2018-09-03 22:23:45.808  WARN 2820 --- [nio-8085-exec-5] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection to http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=PLURALSIGHT-FASTPASS-CONSOLE : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404 
2018-09-03 22:23:45.808  WARN 2820 --- [nio-8085-exec-2] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Failed opening connection to http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=PLURALSIGHT-FASTPASS-CONSOLE : 404 : HTTP/1.1 404
```

Comment: I was using Zuul to protect my API, in this configuration of the session I block the CORS options of Zuul, this configuration are blocking the Hystrix dashbord because of that the browser are unable to present the metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sayali I tried recreating the error in my own system and I managed to get it working, here are a few checks you can make:

1) The URL in your 1st screenshot is incorrect. Your stream URL in the Hystrix Dashboard should be:

> > http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=PLURALSIGHT-TOLLRATE-BILLBOARD

The url should be pointing to the port of the dashboard application that has `@EnableTurbine` annotation in your main class.

2) Check if you are getting a response for:

> > http://localhost:8082/actuator/hystrix.stream

(use your browser for this)
(this should be coming from the application you have enabled hystrix on using `@EnableCircuitBreaker`)

If you're getting pings, then atleast your hystrix stream is accessible.
 If not,
Check if you have: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator` in dependencies and
make sure you have the below property set in application.properties file of the application that has `@EnableCircuitBreaker` in the main class:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= hystrix.stream, info, health
```

Check the URL again.

3) Please get the turbine section working before moving to turbine streams, so as of now, you can make the following change:

```
@EnableTurbine // instead of @EnableTurbineStream
@SpringBootApplication
public class HystrixTurbineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixTurbineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also, to use TurbineStream:

> you might want to have your Hystrix commands push metrics to Turbine.
>   Spring Cloud enables that with messaging. To do so on the client, add
>   a dependency to spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream and the
>   spring-cloud-starter-stream-* of your choice.

refer: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#_turbine_stream

I hope this helps. Please comment to help me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue ?

Comment: Could you pls guide me here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431036/spring-boot-v2-2-6-release-and-turbine-unable-to-aggregate-the-metrix ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry late reply.
Add following configuration to instance that serve hystrix.stream

```
hystrix.dashboard.proxyStreamAllowList: '**'
```